# UserManager not updating User after changes to a property .net7

Tags: c#, controller, blazor, asp.net-identity, usermanager

I'm getting an "ConcurrencyFailure" with "Optimistic concurrency failure, object has been modified." message after trying to save a new object to a list.

I tried the methods with the row version and `[ConcurrencyCheck]` in the property but still no success.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));

user!.Websites.Add(website);

IdentityResult result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

if(result.Succeeded)
{
    return Ok(user.Websites);
}
```

I understand the concept of the optimistic failure and pessimistic one but i still can't manage to update the user.

I get the changes in the context but not to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency problems are caused when two processes are trying to use the same [DbContext] resource at the same time.  Blazor is inherently asynchronous, so the chances of concurrency problems are pretty high.  The problem is solved by using a DbContext Factory and *Unit of Work* contexts.

However, that's not so easy with the UserManager without a lot of coding.  Someone may have a quick answer to that.

You're probably trying to do something like the code below.  You haven't given much away about what the rest of the code looks like, so I'm *Educated Guessing* here.  I may be wide of the mark!

The problem in the below example is that `UpdateUser` yields on `await _UserManager.UpdateAsync(_user)` [that's one open connection on the DbContext], and the UI handler calls `StateHasChanged` which then calls `var user in _UserManager.Users`: an attempt to use a context that's already in use.

You can either:

1. Do everything synchronously.
2. Do what I've show which is override the `ComponentBase` UI handler `HandleEventAsync` with a version that doesn't call `StateHasChanged`.  You do it manually when you need to: in the code after `UpdateUser` finishes with the context.

```cs
@page "/"
@implements IHandleEvent
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> _UserManager

<h3>UserManager</h3>

@foreach( var user in _UserManager.Users )
{
    <div class=" m-1 p-1 bg-dark text-white mb-3">
        <div>
            User Name: @user.UserName
        </div>
        <div>
            Id: @user.Id
        </div>
        <div>
            Phone: @user.PhoneNumber
        </div>
    </div>
}

<input class="form-control mb-3" @bind=this.phone />

<div class="m-2 text-end">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.UpdateUser>Update User's Phone Number</button>
</div>

@code {
    private string? phone;
    private IdentityUser? _user;

    private async Task UpdateUser()
    {
        _user = _UserManager.Users.First();

        if (_user is not null)
        {
            _user.PhoneNumber = this.phone;
            var result = await _UserManager.UpdateAsync(_user);
        }
        // Manual refresh after the _UserManager action completes
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
    // This overrides the standard double render handler 
    // with a simple handler that does no automatic calls to StateHasChanged.
    // It's up to you if and when you call it
    async Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
        => await callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
}
```